# Completely uninstall iOS App and all associated data

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, applications, xcode

**Background**

I am a server-side developer working on an API for an iOS app. From time to time as we are in development (when we have big database changes) we reset our server. This process clears all the server-side data for a member including any App device tokens used for push notifications.

**Problem**

At the same time as I reset the server database I have been trying to uninstall the app and delete any associated app data. I was hoping that if I did this the next time I install the App it would be like it was a first time download again. This is not working.

**How I am doing this:**

I have tried the steps listed on the following site https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/remove_app_from_device.html.

I have also tried uninstalling via the phone:

Under Settings > General > Usage > STORAGE > Manage Storage. I have been clicking on the app and then clicking Delete App;

Under Settings > General > Usage > ICLOUD > Manage Storage. I have been clicking on the current device, then selecting the app and turning off backup and deleting.

I had hoped that this would remove all data so that when I reinstall via Xcode or Test Flight App, the app would start just like a first time user again. However this is not happening. The app still seems to remember some settings, in particular it thinks I have already sent my device token and won't prompt me for it again.

**Question**

How should I be uninstalling an app form a device so that all app data is removed and the next time a reinstall I am treated as a new user?

Comment: Did you reset the device (press and hold Home and Sleep until the Apple logo appears) between deleting the app and reinstalling it? App data is not truly deleted until the device has been reset, and if you reinstall an app before that occurs, it will reuse the old data.

Comment: Yes, that seems to help with most settings (Not PUSH Notifications). I also had to make sure I was logged out of the app or session information would be stored in the keychain.  I still seem to be having issues with the push notification settings, no matter what I do I cannot make the app think I am a new user and prompt me to resend the device ID to our server.

Comment: @tubedogg, Reset the device? Wouldn't that delete everything? How would one go about deleting just the app and its data alone?

Comment: I am sure that @tubedogg suggested to restart the operating system on the iPhone.

Comment: @tubegodd That is not a reset, it is simply a restart of the iPhone.

Comment: @Pacerier Resetting in the manner I described does not remove anything except permanently unlinking data marked for deletion and caches that are designed to be rebuilt.

Comment: @Todd No. Restarting is done by holding Sleep + Volume Up. The hard reset for an iPhone is done by pressing and releasing Volume Up, then Volume Down, then holding Sleep until the Apple logo appears. It's akin to force shutting down a Mac by holding the power button, then turning it back on. A restart is orderly and lets the system wind itself down gracefully; a (hard) reset is not. It also resets things that are not necessarily cleared when you do a normal restart or power cycle, and can resolve minor problems with caches and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

1. Go to Settings --> General --> (iPhone/iPad/iPod/ect.)Storage --> Select app and "Delete App"
2. Go to Settings --> Profiles & Device Management (Could also be called "Profiles", if you don't use this feature, it will not be there) and delete any app data.
3. Go to Settings --> [Your Name] (At the very top) --> iCloud --> Manage Storage --> Select the app and "Delete Data"
4. Delete and re-install the "Test Flight" app
5. Completely reset the device (Press and hold Home and Sleep until the Apple logo appears)

5a. If this device is only for testing, you can go to Settings --> General --> Reset --> Reset All Settings

6. Reinstall the app

Let me know if it works!

Comment: It didn't work for me. I am still finding secure Push Notifcation Tokens

Comment: Did you do 5a???

Comment: No, whilst this is a device I develop on it is alos my personal device so I cannot Reset All Settings, sadly