# Clearing cache and configuration settings for iOS apps

Tags: ios, applications

iOS noob here.

How do I go about deleting all of the configuration and/or cache for a single iOS app?  My goal isn't to simply uninstall the app, but rather to delete all the app's settings to make it act like it's a brand-new download with no configuration yet.

(I'm used to Android where I can go into the Application Storage and click "Clear Data" and "Clear Storage" to delete everything except the app.)

Comment: Is this a generic question about apps in general, or do you have a specific app in mind? [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175897/completely-uninstall-ios-app-and-all-associated-data?rq=1) at AskDifferent may hold a clue.

Comment: The particular app I'm trying to purge is Cisco Jabber, a corporate phone app to allow employees to directly call each other's extensions.  I'm trying to "start fresh" and have the employee login again as if they were logging in for the first time with no residual data existing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an iOS app is uninstalled, its settings and data are uninstalled with it.

Sometimes, you'll notice that when you reinstall the app, it will 'remember' some data from the previous install.  That's because apps can store info on your device **and** on their servers.

Some apps store your info on their systems or 3rd party providers and they identify your device that way. Sometimes it's as simple as the email address you provide when you create your account.

Also, Apple allows developers to call their developer framework to get a unique number for each device.  That a developer can access and store that number on their servers so they'll know if the same device or account has used their app in the past.  The only way around that is to completely wipe your device and set it up as new again.

As each app developer is different, and you don't know what code they implemented, the only way to find out if you can setup the app as brand-new again is to contact the developer or delete the app, restart your device, and reinstall the app again.

Comment: Oh, everything purges by simply uninstalling the app!  I had no idea that all of the residual data is removed - I figured there was a residual cache somewhere in case the user reinstalled the app.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a clarification for a related context: If an app is *automatically* removed because a user has the *Offload Unused Apps* option enabled in iOS 11 or above, then all documents and data are still kept on the device in case the user wants to reinstall the app later. So if a user wants to ensure that any data is actually gone, they need to delete the app manually or, if it was automatically removed by iOS, reinstall the app and then remove it manually so that any data is also removed.

Comment: @puterguy01 the reply states :That's because apps can store info on your device: so I don't think "Oh, everything purges by simply uninstalling the app! " is an accurate assessment

Comment: Once an app is deleted (not offloaded for space), unless its data is also stored in iCloud, its data will be deleted from the device entirely. Apps cannot leave data on a device after deletion. Data is not, however, immediately purged from the device upon deletion of the app. A hard reset has to occur (on Face ID devices, press and release Volume up, press and release Volume down, press and hold Sleep until the Apple logo appears) before the data is actually fully unlinked.